# How do I turn these if statements into switch-case C#

Tags: c#

I need to turn these If statements into Switch-case statements. I get syntax errors when I do. I tried using smth. like:

```
switch(field.text){
case field.text.contains("+"):
field.text=a+b;
break;
}
```

but "field.text.contains("+")" has a syntax error.

I need help, please.
This is my code:

This is the Calculator app, doing simple 2 operators math.

This is the method that splits the string in 2 in order to find the 2 entered numbers :

```
public void GetNumbers(ref string first, ref string second, int place, out int firstNumber, out int secondNumber)
{
    if (place > 0)
    {
        first = ResultFiled.Text.Substring(0, place);

        second = ResultFiled.Text.Substring(place + 1);
    }

    Int32.TryParse(first, out firstNumber);
    Int32.TryParse(second, out secondNumber);
}

private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string first = null;
    string second = null;
    int result = 0;
    int place = 0;
    int firstNumber = 0;
    int secondNumber = 0;
```

Identify the operator in the entered numbers in the Calculator form, then find where it is. Split the string in 2, to find the first and last number. Then do the math operation.

Add 2 numbers

```
    if (ResultFiled.Text.Contains("+"))
    {
        place = ResultFiled.Text.IndexOf("+");

        GetNumbers(ref first, ref second, place, out firstNumber, out secondNumber);

        result = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        ResultFiled.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    else
    {
```

Subtract 2 numbers

```
        if (ResultFiled.Text.Contains("-"))    
        {
            place = ResultFiled.Text.IndexOf("-");
            GetNumbers(ref first, ref second, place, out firstNumber, out secondNumber);

            result = firstNumber - secondNumber;

            ResultFiled.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }

    else
    {
```

Multiply 2 numbers

```
        if (ResultFiled.Text.Contains("*"))
        {
            place = ResultFiled.Text.IndexOf("*");
            GetNumbers(ref first, ref second, place, out firstNumber, out secondNumber);

            result = firstNumber * secondNumber;

            ResultFiled.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }

        else
        {
```

Divide 2 numbers

```
            if (ResultFiled.Text.Contains("/"))
            {
                place = ResultFiled.Text.IndexOf("/");
                GetNumbers(ref first, ref second, place, out firstNumber, out secondNumber);

                try
                {
                    result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                }
                catch (DivideByZeroException exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }

                ResultFiled.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
            }
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need them to be switch statements?

Comment: You can't. at least, not directly. c# switch statement can only work with constants (until c#7).

Comment: Any half-decent expression parser should have [a lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).  Code that splits up the input string in syntactical elements and assigns them an *enum* to classify the element.  Everything else now gets a lot easier, including writing switch statements.

Answer (score 3):

First create enum `MathOp`:

```
  enum MathOp {Null, Add, Sub, Mult, Div }
```

then:

```
  var op = 
     txt.Contains("+")? MathOp.Add:
     txt.Contains("-")? MathOp.Sub:
     txt.Contains("*")? MathOp.Mult:
     txt.Contains("/")? MathOp.Div: 
                        MathOp.Null;

  switch (op)
  {
      case (MathOp.Add):
         ...

      case (MathOp.Sub):
         ...

  }
```